# Refreshing UI in android activity whenever Database is updated in server

Tags: android, mysql

I'm developing an android app which stores data in database on server side. Now i want to refresh the activity whenever a database is updated how can i do this. My application is like a chat application where if i put a request it should be send to the selected users

Answer (score 0):

use FCM(push notifications) [cloud-messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

Answer (score 0):

1.Send push notification from server whenever the database is updated and listen to the notification and Update your UI. 
2.Incase you want to do it without push notification you can also do the polling to the server fire an API based on the frequency required and based on the flag from server update the UI(This may drain the battery of the user because of unwanted polling
)

Comment: now can i send push notification only to certain users

Comment: Yes you can , by taking their fcm registration id stored on your backend server. Please see firebase notification console it has many more feature what you are looking for.

Comment: can you give me an example where by clicking a button i can send notification to selected users